# Deleting Exact Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have around 2000 exact duplicates in table and I want to delete one of them is there a way:
The sample data looks like:

```
Year    ID   Name   Type
2015    200  John   S
2015    200  John   S 
2014    100  Peter  T
2014    100  Peter  T
```

and I want output as :

```
Year    ID   Name   Type
2015    200  John   S
2014    100  Peter  T
```

I have tried using Row_number but not sure how to delete

Comment: You want to delete *one* or you want to delete *all but one*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to ***KEEP*** one row, not ***DELETE*** one row. It also wasn't clear if you only wanted to target this specific set of values or handle all sets of duplicates.

```
;WITH x(y,i,n,t,r) AS 
(
  SELECT [Year], ID, Name, [Type],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year], ID, Name, [Type] ORDER BY [Year])
  FROM dbo.table_name
  /*
    WHERE [Year] = 2015
    AND ID = 200
    AND Name = 'John'
    AND [Type] = 'S'
  */
)
DELETE x WHERE r > 1;
```

If you want to delete one row and keep 1999 duplicates, then change the last line to:

```
DELETE x WHERE r = 1;
```

If you want to only handle this set, remove the `/*` and `*/`.

I also recommend staying away from bad column names like `year` and `type` (they require square brackets in a lot of cases) and `ID` (what does that mean?).